# i am trying to use Draw line and draw oval in java

Tags: java

```
public class MousePointer extends GameFigure {

    public final int SIZE = 10;

    public MousePointer(int x, int y){
        super(x,y);
    }
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2.drawLine((int)location.x - SIZE,(int) location.y,
                (int) location.x + SIZE, (int)location.y);
        g2.drawLine((int)location.x, (int)location.y - SIZE,
                (int)location.x,(int)location.y + SIZE);
        g2.drawOval((int)location.x - SIZE,(int)location.y - SIZE,(int)location.x-SIZE,(int)location.y - SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        // NA/
    }

    @Override
    public int getCollisionRadius() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am trying to create like a sniper image for a game and it is not letting me do that.how its showing up:

[image]

how i want it to look like even when i move my mouse:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is telling java x and y positions of the top left corner of your oval or ellipse whatever you want to call it really.
Base java doesn't have a center translation function, you will need to math that yourself by taking width/2 and height/2 of the ellipse.